# java regex - reading numbers that includes decimal point

Tags: java, regex

This is my current regex:

```
\b(\.|(\+|-)?)\d+(\.\d+)?
```

It reads:

```
100
10.1
```

However, if the number starts with a decimal point it only reads the number after the point. [regex in question with sample texts.](https://regex101.com/r/8OREoj/1)

Comment: your regex doesn't work for values like `-.123` either but would match for a value like `.123.456`

Comment: Try [`[-+]?(?:\b\d+\.|\B\.)?\b\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/2eLd0L/1)

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling I came up with

```
^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$
```

This should match the different types of number representations (except scientific syntax like `1.234E56`. But googling for `regex number` should provide you with plenty of examples if my version is not what you need.

Or is your problem something completely different. IF yes, please provide actual source code and explain what you try to achieve and where you need which value.

Comment: `3.` is also valid in some programming languages.

Comment: @Henry True, but not mentioned in the question ;-)